# Recreating SVN wc.db

Tags: sqlite, svn, version-control

Some of our development teams have had issues with their working copies and it appears that the wc.db database is corrupt. Is there a quick way to repair or rebuild the database instead of doing a fresh checkout?

The error message I get is  **"no such table: wcroot"**, and the OS is Windows 7 and using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) 1.7.6.

Even though this is a specific error, what is the best option when the SQLite database gets corrupted besides doing a full checkout?

Comment: please provide additional informations like: exact error message, svn client(+version), svn server and OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) proposes a tool that repairs some kinds or wc.db corruption (Modify|Validate admin area), retrieving missing/incorrect information from the repository. I'm not sure it will help, but just try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try SmartSVN. I was hoping to find a solution which I could script or at least there could be a command in SVN to redo the database.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, just downgrade.

There is absolutely no logic in putting all your metadata into an SQLite database; Subversion developers are not that bright. Previously, you had .svn files spread across your checkout ... a .svn folder gets screwed; it happens occasionally. Simple: rename, check it out again, merge local changes - with Subversion 1.7 the solution is to "please check out the 10G again".

If you have a big project, like I do (more than 10 GB), and you cannot afford to check out the whole stuff on a monthly basis, downgrade Subversion.

Comment: Sparse checkouts are what you want. As it is, I've not seen a corrupted wc.db yet, and there are very, very few reports of corruption on the internet. That said, I've just looked at the date of the question!

Comment: Yes it is rare but we have checkouts of over 150GB and those are sparse checkouts. The real problem is the lack of good open source/free content management as the majority of the large files are assests, I'm in the video game industry.

Comment: @JohnBowker all you need to do is use subversion <1.7, that works pretty well for me, so far.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the problem is, it's difficult to diagnose. The easiest is to perform a new checkout (and then copy or merge any local changes across).

There are some suggestions you could try [listed here](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/WC-database-corruption-1-7-1-td142807.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the reason because of my machine is out of storage.
After free up some spaces, them problem is gone.